# Issue in importing R library from python (jupyter notebook) ,it returns error "rpy2.rinterface.NULL"

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Hello I am trying to import R packages to be used in one of my python notebook. But whenever I run the code it returns me 'rpy2.rinterface.NULL'

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importer
base = importr('base')
print(base.R_home())
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importer
utils = importr("utils")
import rpy2.robjects.packages as packages
utils = rpackages.importr('utils')
utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1) # select the first mirror in the list
```

It gives me error

```
rpy2.rinterface.NULL
```

and again if I try to import any packages it again gives me same error

```
packnames = ('ggplot2', 'hexbin')
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector
utils.install_packages(StrVector(packnames))
```

Error:

```
rpy2.rinterface.NULL
```